# Spring Boot: how to configure a set of implementations to inject?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, configuration

In my Spring Boot app, I have **events** that should be **reported** in various ways, depending on the environment.

I defined `interface IReporter` and several implementations, namely `LogReporter`, `EmailReporter`, `RpcReporter`. Also new implementations may appear in future.

Now I want my events to be reported using a subset of reporters. The subset must be specified in the app configuration as the following (for example):

```
events.reporters=LogReporter,EmailReporter
```

or

```
events.reporters=${EVENT_REPORTERS}
```

or something similar.

As a result, I would like the component that handles events (say `class EventHandler`) to have *magically* injected `List<IReporter> myReporters` containing only the necessary implementations.
And, of course, if a new implementation is created, the only thing to update must be the app configuration (not the code of `EventHandler`).

I'm familiar with injecting all available implementations, only a `@Primary` implementation, or a specific one picked with `@Qualifier`. But looks like these do not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class EventHandler {

        @Value("${events.reporter}")
        List<String> requiredImplementation;

        @Autowired
        List<IReporter> myReporters;

        public List<IReporter> getRequiredImplementation() {
            return myReporters.stream()
                    .filter(reporter -> requiredImplementation.contains(reporter.getClass().getSimpleName()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
One option I could think if we want framework to autowire only the required beans, we can explore @ConditionalOnExpression.

For instance:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{'${events.reporter}'.contains('LogReporter')}")
Class LogReporter {
}

@Component
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{'${events.reporter}'.contains('EmailReporter')}")
Class EmailReporter {
}
```

Comment: Well, the _magic_ is done manually here. Injecting everything and filtering out what is not necessary. However, the framework will try to instantiate all reporters. Some of them may fail due to absent resources. For example, if I don't use `EmailReporter`, I won't provide parameters for access to SMTP.

Comment: Edited my answer to include an option for auto configuring only required beans based on the property values.

Comment: Thanks, @kumar-v This is exactly what I was looking for - **conditional beans**.

Comment: @NikS Glad to know it helped. Can you accept this answer if this solved your problem?